# How can I integrate $\exp(−\sin(θ))\cos(θ+\cos(θ))$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, complex-integration

The question refers to the contour integration of  $\exp(−\sin(θ))\cos(θ+\cos(θ))$

I know I have to use residue theorem somehow, but I can't realise

[Here's what I tried to do, but it doesn't match to the statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbDdX.png)

Comment: Just calculate $\oint_{|z|=1} e^{1/z}dz$ both by Resiude's Theorem and by parametrizing the unit circle.

Comment: Should both ways give the same result?

Comment: Yeah. By Residue, you'll get a (complex) number.
By the other method, you'll get your real integral (as real or imaginary part. So you only have to match.

Comment: @Matteo, that question is the same of this one, asked in a different time and left unanswered

Comment: By residue, you get only the definite integral.  This question seems to ask for the indefinite integral.  This does have a simple to write indefinite integral.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to find $$\int_0^{2\pi} \exp(-\sin\theta)\cos(\theta+\cos\theta)d\theta$$a famous method for solving such contour integral is to assume $z=\exp(i\theta)$ with the contour being $|z|=1$. In this case, $dz=izd\theta$, $\sin\theta={1\over 2i}(z-z^{-1})$, $\cos\theta={1\over 2}(z+z^{-1})$ and this integral is equivalent to $${1\over i}\int \exp({i\over 2}(z-z^{-1}))\left[{1\over 2}(z+z^{-1})\cos \left({1\over 2}(z+z^{-1})\right)-{1\over 2i}(z-z^{-1})\sin \left({1\over 2}(z+z^{-1})\right)\right]{dz\over z}$$which has a singularity in $z=0$. The rest of the solution is left to you by using the Laurant series of the integrand around $z=0$.

> (Hint: you only need to find the constant term in 
>   $$\exp({i\over 2}(z-z^{-1}))\left[{1\over 2}(z+z^{-1})\cos \left({1\over 2}(z+z^{-1})\right)-{1\over 2i}(z-z^{-1})\sin \left({1\over 2}(z+z^{-1})\right)\right]$$
>   )

Comment: Thanks!  I know that 1/z = -1/z + z^-2 - z^-3... and cos z = 1 - z^2/2! + z^4/4!, but it's seems so tough, I don't know how to use Laurent series properly. Could you give me some more clues??

Answer (score 0):

$e^{iz}$ is an entire function, so by Cauchy's Theorem 
$$\oint_{|z|=1} e^{iz}dz =0$$

On the other hand, using the parametrization of the unit circle $\gamma(t)=e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t$, $t\in[0,2\pi]$, we have that
$$0=\oint_{|z|=1} e^{iz}dz = \int_0^{2\pi} e^{i{\gamma(t)}}\gamma'(t)dt = \int_0^{2\pi} e^{-\sin t+i\cos t} i e^{it}dt =
i \int_0^{2\pi} e^{-\sin t+(t+\cos t)i}dt =$$ $$=i\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-\sin t}\left(\cos(t+\cos t) + i \sin(t+\cos t)\right)dt
$$
Hence, 
$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-\sin t}\cos(t+\cos t)dt=0=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-\sin t}\sin(t+\cos t)dt$$

Comment: Thank you!!! I've finally understood it!